# Is it possible to trigger automated test suite/plan from manual suite in azure dev ops without having visual studio

Tags: eclipse, selenium, azure-devops

I'm new to Azure DevOps . Our requirement is to fire the automation test suite which coded in eclipse , resides in a devops repo and linked with a pipeline . There is a manual suite which is related to the automation suite and will trigger the automation suite . I don't use Visual studio . As per my latest knowledge Microsoft is yet to provide support.Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Did you mean the manual suite also host by Azure DevOps? If so, what's the relationship between it with your code hosted in eclipse?

Comment: Did you mean the manual suite also host by Azure DevOps? - Yes

Answer (score 0):

No, it's **not able to do** this without Visual Studio.

> Tests can be run in the CI/CD pipeline by choosing the test plan or
> test suite in the settings of the Visual Studio Test task. Automated
> tests can also be run from Azure Test Plans or the Test hub in Azure
> DevOps Server (see Web portal navigation). If you are using XAML
> builds you can also run these automated tests by using Microsoft Test
> Manager.

The process to associate an automated test with a test case is:

- Use Visual Studio Enterprise or Professional 2017 or a later version
  to associate the automated test with a test case as shown below. The
  test case must have been added to a test plan that uses the build you
  just defined.

You may have to do this with Visual Studio as a prerequisite. Details please refer our official doc here -- **[Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops)**